# Open App Store 'Featured' page (not a specific app) from a link.

Tags: ios, app-store

I know that an app can be linked to directly from an URL so that when it is clicked on my phone, the AppStore app will open and guide me to the app in question *but* is it possible to link to the 'Featured' page (or better still the 'Redeem' page of AppStore from a link?

The scenario is I send a promo code for AppXYZ out in an email and the recipient can click that email link and be taken to (a) the AppStore app or (b) the AppStore app Redeem page passing the code through.

I know the link for something similar in iTunes but not AppStore. Can't seem to find any info other than links to specific apps (which I don't want).

**iTunes:** `itmss://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/freeProductCodeWizard?code=THE_CODE`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redeem a code on the App Store it nevertheless always goes through the link you provided, but correctly spelled:

`itms://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/freeProductCodeWizard?code=THE_CODE`

It opens the iTunes app on iOS with the code filled in, the user still has to tap on redeem as it's still a transaction. If he does so, the app will automatically be downloaded (just tested it with the latest iOS version)

I tried to copy a couple of links from the desktop iTunes and checked, if they work on iOS, but the answer is no. E.g.:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/collection/editors-choice/id25204?fcId=531794418&mt=8

https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewRoom?fcId=1188885481&genreIdString=36&mediaTypeString=Mobile+Software+Applications

https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewRoom?fcId=554381198&genreIdString=36&mediaTypeString=Mobile+Software+Applications

(Also tried it with itms:// instead of https://)